# Is it OK to use the index as a key when elements will only be added to the end?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array that only expands at the end, meaning once an element has its index, it keeps it for life. Is it OK to use the index as a key in this case?

Comment: how did I manage to get a downvoter within 30 seconds?

Comment: when I have to use the index I like to combine them with some kind of text to help me Identify them in the Dev Tool (react). something like `key={"button" + index}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main point that presents index as keys as an anti-pattern is that if order changes, React will get confused. Operations such as sorting or splicing can lead this to happen. Since you claim order doesn't change, there's no problem.

Now even if there's no problem, doesn't mean it's necessarily a good idea. It's better to be safe than sorry. If in the future, you introduce order-changing operations, your codebase will be less flexible. I suggest going with a better production-ready and long term solution other than indices.